# How to check if there is a string/s in a list in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import statistics
import time

def medianextra (numlist=[0], i=2):
    Attempt=0
    while not i==0:
        try:
            if not len(numlist)==1:
                try:
                    a = statistics.median(numlist)
                    b = statistics.median_low(numlist)
                    c = statistics.median_high(numlist)
                    print(f"The Median is: {a}")
                    if a != b or a != b:
                        print(f"The Low Median is: {b}")
                        print(f"The High Median is: {c}")

                except BaseException:
                    print("The values are not a numerical number.")    
                except:
                    print("An error occured. Please make sure the values are numerical.")
                break
            elif len(numlist)==(0):
                print("No values detected.")
                break
            elif len(numlist)==(1):
                s = [str(integer) for integer in numlist]
                a_string = "".join(s)
                res = int(a_string)
                print(f"Only one value entered. Median is: {res}")
                break
            else:
                print("An error occured. Please make sure the values are numerical, or values are included.")
                break
            
        except:
            Attempt=Attempt+1
            print("")
            print("Catastrophic failure.")
            print(f"Retrying calculations. Attempt:{Attempt}")
            print(f"Remaining attempts: {i-1}")
            i=i-1
            time.sleep(2)
            if i==0:
                print("\nAttempts failed.\n")
            continue
        
    exit()
```

However, if `numlist` contains a string, the string is counted as the median, and not the integers, such as when you are importing from a file via:

```
data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\...\test.xlsx')
medianextra(data)
```

I am aware that I need a `df = list(data["example_column"])`, however, I was thinking that there could still be a string in the actual columns of the dataset.

Because of this worry, I wanted to ask if there is a way where I could ask "`if string in numlist:...`". This `string` should also be arbitrary, and not based on some preset and specified string value (such as `string = 'a', 'b', 'ab', etc`).

I will also attempt to place this at `<**HERE**>` so that I break the program without it going forward and giving the wrong median value:

```
def medianextra (numlist=[0], i=2):
    <**HERE**>
    Attempt=0
    while not i==0
```

Comment: What do you mean it should not be predefined? You need to define it somewhere? What string do you want to check and where?  Where are you attempting this in your code?

Comment: have you tried this? `if string in numlist:` should work just fine...

Comment: @MadisonCourto @Michael Delgado I mean that `string` should just be any string value that might be in the list. In this case, I would not have specified what `string` is, so it is virtually any `string` that could be created in python. I would also put said if-statement right after the `def medianextra` to break the program without it being able to go to the try-excepts and giving a mathematically false answer.
Also, `if string in numlist:` does not work in my python 3.9.

Comment: Then it's as simple as Michael has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple strings the best option perhaps might be;

```
def check_if_string_in_numlist(*args, numlist):
    for arg in args:
        if arg in numlist:
            return True
    return False
```

Usage:

```
print(check_if_string_in_numlist('a', 'b', 'c', numlist=['a', 'b', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])) # multiple strings
print(check_if_string_in_numlist('a', numlist=[1,'a', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])) # single string
```

EDIT: not sure how else to articulate this so you'll understand; perhaps this will help (you can call this anywhere, with your "arbitrary string"

```
check_if_string_in_numlist(someStringFromSomewhereInYourCode, SomeNumlist) # return true if the string exists in the numlist otherwise false
```

Comment: Forgive me but I do not understand that too well. What would be the *args in this case?

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself that clearly. By "arbitrary, and not based on some preset and specified string value", I mean that I specifically don't want to mention the `'a', 'b', 'c'` or anything else. Thus, I wanted to see if I can just arbitrarily ask if there is a string in `numlist`, regardless of what that string is.

Comment: Yes, you are passing 'a','b' or whatever as an argument, you can make the argument/s whatever you want, but at some point, you'll need to have a reference. "does X have Y in it" Y can't be null forever. It's like looking for a needling in a haystack, but the needle not existing.